# Download Save And Run

Tags: c#, download

I have been trying to download a file and run it than C#, with limited success. Here's my script:

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
{
    Client.DownloadFile("http://vx.zapto.org/newscript/enone.jpg", ".jpeg");
    MessageBox.Show("Downloaded!");
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's not working right?

Comment: -1: "Limited success" is not very clear explanation of a problem.

Answer (score 11):

Try this maybe (if by *run it* you meant open it with default application):

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo("filename.jpeg");
    Client.DownloadFile("http://vx.zapto.org/newscript/enone.jpg", file.FullName);
    MessageBox.Show("Downloaded!");

    Process.Start(file.FullName);
}
```

Note that the second parameter to [`WebClient.DownloadFile(..)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) is a filename, not an extension.

Comment: YES!!! Thank you so much it works perfectly! But would it be possible to save the file that was downloaded to a certain place?

Comment: @user1797443 Certainly - instead of `"filename.jpg"` specify your own location. Did you want a save file dialog?