# Add Download and Execute .exe in C# Program

Tags: c#, download, execute

I search how to add a download & execute function in my tool.
Its a C# Program and i need code for download a .exe file with url and execute them.
I use Visual Studio 2017.

### Thanks for helping me.

Its working with .exe ?

### [Download Save And Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783431/download-save-and-run)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download Save And Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783431/download-save-and-run)

Comment: this is a poorly written question you need to show us what you have tried on your own. just posting `I search how to add a downloand & execute` indicates you haven't put in much effort. this will probably be closed / downvoted because it's very low quality question to say the least

Answer (score -2):

Here is a method that takes the direct link of the file you want to download. It will download the file and execute it.

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

void DownloadFileAndExecute(string link)
{
  WebClient wc = New WebClient();
  string filename = Path.GetFileName(link);
  wc.DownloadFile(link, filename)
  Process.Start(filename)
}
```